# How to take a larger photo in Google Sign in?

Tags: android, google-signin

I am developing a project for Android and do authorization through Google Sign in. When I get a user profile photo, I have it in a small size. How do I take a larger user profile photo?

Comment: You can resize the image after receiving it, do you think that resize it will harm the picture quality? tell me if you don't mind to use that solution and i can even give you code sample

Comment: @TamirAbutbul Thank you for answering my question, but the resolution of the photo is very small 96x96 and when you expand the size of the photo quality will decrease.